# How to animate popup window from bottom to top in android

Tags: android, animation, popup

How to animate popup window from bottom to top and place the window at user clicked place  in android can anybody provide code

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

**values\style.xml**:

```
<resources>
<style name="AnimationPopup">
    <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/appear</item>
    <item name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/disappear</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

**anim\appear.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<scale
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="90%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

**anim\disappear.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<scale
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="90%"
    android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />
</set>
```

Comment: I use popWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.AnimationPopup);  to set animation,but it have no effect

Answer (score 4):

use this xmls to translate from bottom to top and vice versa.

**anim\pull_in.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

**anim\pull_out.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />
</set>
```